# How to use + in sql sever

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a join query. Table A has a Primary Key = 123456000000 and table B has foreign key = 123456.

I want to know how can i join the 2 tables using inner join using + in query

I wrote the following -

```
SELECT RAP.COL1, FRE.COL2 FROM Table 1 AS RAP
INNER JOIN Table 2 AS FRE
ON RAP.COL1+'000000' = FRE.COL2

NOTE - COL2 = 123456000000
COL1 = 123456
```

I NEED TO ADD 000000 so that i can join. BUT THE ABOVE WRITTEN DOES NOT WORK :(

Please help
Cheers
OZ

Comment: I think you need to convert RAP.COL1 to varchar if you want to concatenate the strings.

Comment: What is the datatype of these 2 columns? How can they have a relationship, when the data in the PK and that in the FK columns are different?

Comment: These are basically deal id's for trades. only 000000 is added as an extra integer rest 123456 is a deal id.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, but why the keys are different. Any specific reason.

```
SELECT RAP.COL1, FRE.COL2 FROM Table 1 AS RAP
INNER JOIN Table 2 AS FRE
ON (Convert(varchar(20),RAP.COL1)+'000000')as COL1 = FRE.COL2
```

Comment: Please: if you use `varchar` (as a parameter, or in a `CONVERT` statement), please ***ALWAYS*** define a length! Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), RAP.COL1)` instead of what you've got right now...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RAP.COL1, FRE.COL2 FROM Table 1 AS RAP
INNER JOIN Table 2 AS FRE
ON RAP.COL1 = LEFT(FRE.COL2,6)
```